# return value of operator[] on non-existing item in std::map

Tags: c++, return-value, stdmap

While building a container based on std::map I've encountered an unexpected behavior: retrieving a value of a non existing key doesn't provide a new object constructed with default constructor.

What am I missing here?

A reduced test-case program:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <string>


static std::string to_lower(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string lower_label;
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), lower_label.begin(), ::tolower);
    return lower_label;
}

class Int {
   public:
      Int () : i(0) { }
      Int (int _i) : i(_i) { }

      int val() const { return i; }

   private:
      int i;
};

std::map<std::string, Int> ints;

Int GetInt(const std::string& label)
{
    std::string lower_label = to_lower(label);
    return ints[lower_label];
}

void AddInt(Int image, const std::string& label)
{
    std::string lower_label = to_lower(label);
    ints[lower_label] = image;
}

int main()
{
    Int k;
    printf ("default Int: %d\n", k.val());

    AddInt(Int(5), "I5");
    Int i = GetInt("i5");
    printf ("existing Int: %d\n", i.val());

    Int j = GetInt("LaLa");
    printf ("non-existing Int:  %d\n", j.val());  // expecting 0

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
default Int: 0
existing Int: 5
non-existing Int:  5
```

Comment: Your `transform` writes into an empty string, you need to use a `back_insert_iterator`

Comment: It should also use `std::tolower` and ensure that invalid values aren't passed in: `[](unsigned char c) {return std::tolower(c);}`. You'll also need to `#include <cctype>`.

Comment: You could have caught this if you wrote tests for your code. Testing the `to_lower` function would have revealed it is completely broken and doesn't return the right string. `std::cout << to_lower("I5");` would have been better than nothing. Why don't you test your code? Asking StackOverflow is not a substitute for testing.

Comment: @Jonathan: that small piece of code somehow fell out of coverage in the unit test :) It's easier to write tests than rewrite a piece of code to make it paste-able here as a well defined question. I was sure I'm missing something about std::map. Thanks for your comments and answer.

Comment: @chris, changing ::tolowor to std::tolower in the code breaks compilation (no matching function call). Why are you suggesting this change? Can you provide a substitute line of code to the std::transform line with your suggestion?

Comment: `<cctype>` is guaranteed to declare `std::tolower` and _might_ also declare `::tolower`, but is not guaranteed to. `<ctype.h>` is guaranteed to declare `::tolower` and _might_ also declare `std::tolower`, but is not guaranteed to. `<locale>` declares an overload of `std::tolower` taking two arguments. You don't include any of those headers, so it's not clear which functions will be defined. It turns out that both forms of `std::tolower` are declared, so simply saying `&std::tolower` is ambiguous. The lambda @chris wrote would not be ambiguous, as long as `<cctype>` is included.

Comment: Converting to `unsigned char` is necessary to ensure you don't pass a negative `char` to `std::tolower(int)` / `::tolower(int)`, because that's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `transform` writes into an empty string, so the program has undefined behaviour.

What happens in practice is that `lower_label` still has length zero when you return it, so every time you call `to_lower` you get the same key back: an empty string. That means your map has one entry and the same entry gets returned by every call to `GetInt`.

But as you have undefined behaviour you're lucky it doesn't crash or wipe your disk.

You need to use a `back_insert_iterator` or set the string size correctly before you try writing to it.

Either:

```
  std::string lower_label;
  std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(lower_label), ::tolower);
```

Or:

```
  std::string lower_label;
  lower_label.resize(str.size());
  std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), lower_label.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Comment: Does `back_inserter` work on a string `begin`? A certain compiler I have to hand says `Error 1 error C2039: 'push_back' : is not a member of 'std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>`

Comment: @doctorlove, doh, it should be `std::back_inserter(lower_label)` (as your answer says), thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your `to_lower` function (you don't need it to be `static` either) so that it has somewhere to put the lower case characters:

```
std::string to_lower(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string lower_label;
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(lower_label), ::tolower);
    return lower_label;
}
```

then it's fine:
default Int: 0
existing Int: 5
non-existing Int:  0